# Having troubles with a correct connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I have been looking around on the internet to find the proper connection string format, but I find different ones all over the place from different topics posted years between. I can't seem to find the right one. I am using a MySQL Database installed as a Windows Service.

[image: Database Picture]

[image: Connection String]

Printed here is my Connection String (I removed the Port after this picture was taken and the last semicolon is there but I omitted it accidentally). But I get the following error message:

[image: Error Message]

I get Error 40 from this. Anyone know the actual correct format? I feel stupid for asking haha

**EDIT:**

As Requested, instantiation Code for the Connection:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Data Source=MySQL;");
sb.Append("Server=" + Server + ";");
sb.Append("Database=" + Database + ";");
sb.Append("UID=" + UserID + ";");
sb.Append("PWD=" + Password + ";");
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sb.ToString());
conn.Open();
return conn;
```

Comment: Post the code where you are instantiating the connection conn.

Comment: Sure, added the code for future reference.

Comment: Might want to consider using the ConnectionStringBuilder class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @TiesonT. Ah yeah I remember I read that somewhere...I just forgot about it in the meantime haha. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is searching for an SQL Server, whereas you want it to connect it to a MySQL database. I guess you are using SQLConnection to connect to the database. That will not work.

You need to either use OleDBConnection or MySQLConnection object to connect to a MySQL database.

Comment: Huh. I guess that makes sense. Yeah I am using the SqlConnection. Changing it to MySqlConnection found in the MySql.Data assembly di the trick. Thanks!